# Find a matrix which is orthogonal to two given matrix w.r.t the given inner product $\langle S,T\rangle = \text{Tr}(ST)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

> Show that $\langle S,T\rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(ST)$ is an inner product on a vector space $V$ of of $3×3$ real symmetric matrices where $\operatorname{Tr}$ is trace of a matrix.

I've worked my way out to show that it is inner product.

But w.r.t. this inner product when I'm trying to find a matrix that is orthogonal to both $S_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$ and $S_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\0 & -3 & 0\\1 & 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$, I can only find out using the definition if the inner product the elements $a,b,e$ of the orthogonal matrix  $T =\begin{pmatrix}a & d & e\\d & b & f\\e & f &c\end{pmatrix}$.

How can I compute the other elements? Do i need to, because the entries that I found out are only determining the trace of their products to be 0?

Comment: hint: relate it to the Frobenius norm

Comment: But how, I am not getting it.

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the fact that the diagonal entries of $A^2$ are the sum of the squared modulus of vectors (since $A$ symmetric), and since $A\neq 0$ at least one entry is non-zero?

Comment: Yes I get it. Simply multiplying a symmetric matrix to itself I got it.

Comment: the sum of those diagonal entries is known as the squared Frobenius norm

Comment: Sure, sounds a bit overcomplicated for the scope of this problem though

Comment: Another way to establish this is to express $\text{Tr}(A^t A)$ as a sum over the matrix elements. The resulting expression will be manifestly positive for any $A\neq 0.$ (This avoids any need to appeal to the spectral theorem.)

Comment: It should be said that your newly edited post, including the title, has almost **nothing** to do with the original post that generated the above comments.  Anyway you have a vector space and an inner product, so pick a vector that is linearly independent of your vectors $S_1$ and $S_2$ and run Gram Schmidt using your inner product.

Comment: The matrices are sparse enough that you could just eyeball a solution. Note that $\operatorname{Tr}(AB)$ is basically just the dot product, if you vectorised these matrices (i.e. the sum of the products of the entries). If you pick a matrix with, say, with mostly $0$ entries, except for one or two carefully chosen $1$ entries, then you might stumble on a good example.